# power at voltage variation

Tags: power

220V/5W means consumption of 5W at 220 volts. That implies 0.0227A current.How will this device operate at 110 volts? What will be the power consumption and how much will be the current?Sorry for bad english

Comment: Which device? Who said it will work on 110V at all?

Comment: Impossible to tell. It depends on the device. It may be more it may be less it may be the same it may not work it may blow up...

Comment: it will not work.but why?consider a ordinary bulb

Comment: Ordinary bulb is pretty close to a resistor. Can you think of how it will work?

Comment: 220V, 5W draws 0.0227A. And at same power, 110 volts it needs to draw 0.045 A mathematically. It could have worked in this way.But why not?

Comment: basically, what i am confused at is whether or not the power remains constant at different voltage supply

Comment: that's up to the device.

Comment: Except in rare occasions the power will not be constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power, voltage and current are related by the formula $$ P = VI \tag 1$$.

For a resistive load we can make some substitutions from Ohm's Law, \$ V = IR \$. This results in $$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} \tag 2$$ and $$ P = I^2 R \tag 3$$.

From (2) we can see that if R remains constant and we halve the voltage then the power will be 1/4. So if your 220 V, 5 W load example is a resistor then on 110 V it will dissipate 5/4 = 1.25 W.

[image]

*Figure 1. A bulb running on reduced voltage.*

Your bulb example is a resistor load but the resistance is temperature dependent. At high temperatures the resistance increases. This means that at 110 V a 220 V, 5 W bulb might consume somewhat more than 1/4 - maybe 1/3 of its rated power, 5/3 = 1.6 W. The bulb will glow a nice warm shade of orange.

Comment: but what i am seeing in everycircuit app is that when the supply is 220V for the bulb, it glows orange. But once reached 440V supply, the bulb glows bright white. And exceeded, the bulb fuses. I expected bright white at 220V. Was I wrong? And what causes the bulb to fuse out?

Comment: What bulb? Part number? Voltage and wattage?

Comment: He's talking about a simulation, nothing real.  And a bulb even in real life is a non-linear resistive load.