# power voltage and performance of bulb

Tags: voltage, power, current

What i am seeing in is that when the supply is 220V for the bulb (rated 220V,5W), it glows orange. But once reached 440V supply, the bulb glows bright white. And exceeded, the bulb fuses. I expected bright white at 220V since it was rated 5W(which i guess is the maximum power) at 220V. Was I wrong? And what causes the bulb to fuse out?

[image: At 220V]
[image: At 440V]

Comment: are you talking about the color of a lightbulb in the simulation?
  .... whoever wrote the sim chose that color. .... think about what happens in a circuit as you raise the voltage.

Comment: This is basically the same question as you asked 12 hours previously: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337692/power-at-voltage-variation/337715?noredirect=1#comment797363_337715. In that you didn't mention that your observations were based on a simulator. You should have edited that question to clarify instead of asking a second.

Comment: When the voltage is raised,  upto 440V the brightness increase gradually but once 440 exceeded, the bulb fuses out.  I didnt get this since i thought it would fuse when 220V is exceeded. Please point out my mistake

Comment: Please edit both this question and your previous one to be clear that the question is based on the results of a (poor) simulator. Why did you not do this already and provide a link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5W mains powered bulbs aren't generally intended as serious illumination, they are more likely to be used as indicator lamps, so failure means you can't tell that some circuit is powered, which could put you in a dangerous situation.

Also, high voltage low power implies very thin wire which makes the bulb very fragile and impacts its lifetime.

Put these factors together - both factors suggest the bulb should be highly under-rated, for decent lifetime but low illumination efficiency and low colour temperature.

I'm not surprised it significantly exceeded its rated voltage, but I'm a little surprised you got to twice its nominal rating before it failed instantly.

Comment: Brian sir, why would a bulb fail? What are the causes for the bulb to fuse out?

Comment: @GauravBhattarai The filament melts or evaporates

Comment: And why would a filament melt or evaporate? Is it due to higher power supply or something else?

Comment: Because it is heated to its melting point.

Comment: The power you are dissipating in it. This is getting ridiculous.